# libGL Error Failed to Load Driver swrast when executing AppImage from XFCE

Tags: nvidia, xfce, opengl

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with XFCE desktop and am attempting to execute an AppImage from Jetbrains.  I've already modified permissions on the executable but receive the following errors:

```
QXcbConnection: failed to initialize XRandr
Qt: XKEYBOARD extension not present on the X server.
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found.
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I found answers to other questions referencing the fixing of symbolic links to OpenGL.  I did so but the above error persists.  I've reviewed the NVIDIA installation document but am fearful this might be detrimental to my development virtual machine.

Do I need to install the NVIDIA drivers to rectify the above?  If so, will these in turn break other portions of this virtual machine hosted on Azure?  Or, is there a more optimal approach of enabling the AppImage execution on this virtual machine?